# How does high-level assembly instruction get translated into low-level logical gate behaviors?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, logic-gates, assembly

(Pardon me if this is not the best place for such question. I searched a bit but no better place found.)

I learned both assembly language and basic digital circuit design back in college. But after so many years of coding with various languages, I think I still miss the critical knowledge `in the middle of` those 2 parts:

> How does high-level assembly instruction get translated into low-level
>   logical gate behaviors?

AFAIK, the lowest level of a computer is various `logical gates`. For an assembly language instruction such as `movl 10, eax`, I know it will be translated by an assembler into a sequence of 1/0s. But how is that translated into `actions of logical gates`? And I heard there is so-called micro-code for processors. How is that related?

### ADD 1

Thanks to EugeneSh. Below are some useful references:

Nand2Tetris:

- Official site: http://www.nand2tetris.org/
- Coursera: https://www.coursera.org/learn/build-a-computer
- The book: [http://www.amazon.com/Elements-Computing-Systems-Building-Principles/dp/0262640686/ref=ed_oe_p](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262640686)
- Course lecture materials & ebook: http://www1.idc.ac.il/tecs/plan.html
- TED talk: https://www.ted.com/talks/shimon_schocken_the_self_organizing_computer_course

Comment: I suggest you to take [this excellent MOOC](https://www.coursera.org/learn/build-a-computer) (the best on the subject I've seen around). It will answer your question from A to Z. And the best part that it is starting in less than a week.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for the info. I have just enrolled the lesson. It looks promising. It will be an exciting journey *to touch the soul of machine*.

Comment: And btw, I just found there's a TED talk `nand2teris` accompanying this lesson. https://www.ted.com/talks/shimon_schocken_the_self_organizing_computer_course

Comment: It has a dedicated website with all of the materials ready, If you don't like it "official".

Comment: This is of course appropriate subject matter, but the question being asked just goes beyond the scope of a stack overflow answer - the site here exists for questions of contained scope - it is not mean to replace in-depth resources, nor are questions that seek pointers to external resources really considered on topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really can't jump from assembly instructions to gates. Between the assembly language instructions and the actual gates, there is another level of abstraction: the functional circuit blocks.

The assembly language instructions generate control signals to a number of functional blocks. At a minimum there is the instruction decoder, the ALU for arithmetic and the program sequencer for instruction flow. Additionally, there is typically one or two address generators for addressing operands. They could be simple pointers, as in an 8051, or complex arithmetic units themselves, as in a DSP. You often have pipeline registers to allow instructions to flow faster. These days, there are also floating-point and other co-processors.

The workings of each of these blocks can be discussed at length. So we really can't answer that question.

Microcode was one way to simplify those blocks, at the expense of speed. The processor is made very simple, and complex instructions invoke a sequence of micro-instructions, pre-programmed in a "control-store", that run on the simplified hardware. The technique isn't used anymore, since speed is considered much more important than gates. Gates are almost free.